# validating positive number input for float array using scanf in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, validation, floating-point

I have an float array and I need to fill it up with positive numbers, I'd like to do input validation while reading it into the array, if possible while using scanf().

what I would like to do more specifically is use a string array for the input and check the elements one by one with a switch to see if they're digits and then convert them into a float and into the float array.

Could anyone show me an example of how to go about doing this?

Comment: `a[i] > 0` maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scanf()` to parse the numbers and verify the constraint of the converted values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float array[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (scanf("%f", array + i) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input for entry %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (array[i] < 0) {
            printf("entry %d is negative: %f\n", i, array[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // do something with the array:
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    printf("sum is %f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```